# Files Deleted After Accidental Time Machine Restore

Tags: finder, time-machine, macos

I keep all my important schoolwork in different folders on my desktop, and i accidentally entered Time Machine while i was in Finder. Following this, three of my six folders disappeared (they are not in Trash or anywhere else I can find on my computer). 
Please help, I need those files for school and I have no idea what has happened!!!

Update: Time Machine wasn't meant to be running in the first place, and it will not let me access Time Machine anymore

Update 2: Time Machine wasn't meant to be running in the first place, but it opened a couple of 'finder' icons that only spanned until 'Now'. I accidentally hit the 'restore' button, and then 3/6 folders disappeared from my desktop.

Comment: Restore Documents from an earlier Time Machine - anything in Time Machine won't have been deleted from there (unless you are low on disk space on  the TM)

Comment: Just how did you "_accidentally_" enter Time Machine? Regardless, just the act of entering Time Machine is not going to delete anything on your Desktop. I'd say there's more to this story then you're telling, whether or not you really remember what you did.

Comment: So you entered Time Machine. Did you also restore the Desktop folder?

Comment: What happens when you try to enter TM again?

Answer (score 1):

If the interface to Time Machine has you confused, just use Finder and Spotlight. You can browse the snapshots on he backup drive by date and go to your desktop folder to look for the files you need.

When files go missing, it's either directory corruption or a failing drive. Consider lowering off the Mac and taking the drive to another mac to see if you can get at your backups.